# Cannot find module '@ledgerhq/devices/hid-framing'

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm getting the following error when I make yarn start (The npm packages were previously installed without any problem). I'm using es5. The full error consists of these three errors:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@ledgerhq/devices/hid-framing'`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

`index.js:1 ./node_modules/@ledgerhq/hw-transport-webhid/lib-es/TransportWebHID.js`

As far as I know, none of my packages depend on the @ledgerhq/devices package.

I have found some possible solutions, but none of them have worked. Among them I have tried:

I have installed it using
`npm install @ledgerhq/devices`

I tried adding `"alias": {"@ledgerhq/devices": "@ledgerhq/devices/lib-es" }` in package.json

I also tried running it using `npm start -- --reset-cache`